# Angular JS and partials

Tags: angularjs, partial, partials

Is it possible to embed html page in another one in angular js?

If so, how to do it?

[Here](http://docs.angularjs.org/#!/tutorial/step_08) in their tutorial, the partial is not embedded in the page but it's like different page where you go when you click on one of the items. ([see demo](http://angular.github.com/angular-phonecat/step-8/app/#/phones))

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using **ngInclude** directive.

See the docs and example here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Comment: That's terrible. Is there no way to include a partial without invoking a new request, for example, as a reusable fragment in the initial HTML payload?

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Obviously, this should be used sparingly but it worked perfectly to repurpose my login form.

Comment: @davidgoli, as far as I know, angular caches loaded templates to avoid subsequent requests.

Comment: @davidgoli You can define templates in the same page with a script tag, see http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:script

Comment: @davidgoli, the ngInclude directive will make a request to the backend for a partial, but if it already exists in the $templateCache, it will grab it from there first. You can add strings of HTML into the $templateCache like so: $templateCache.put('templateId.html', '<div>This is the content of the template</div>');   This should allow you to add special markup to your main index.html that contains the HTML you want to use as a template, and when the JS kicks in, you can read those elements, pull them in as strings, and add them to your $templateCache so angular can render them in.

Answer (score 7):

If `ng-include` is not what you need, you might want to check out the **angular-ui-router** module. It allows you to do nested and parallel views... It is great, flexible, easy to use and well documented.
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 7):

@Wilt is right, but here is a more specific link and a code sample (from https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-view )

In your root template:

```
<div ui-view></div>
<div ui-view="chart"></div> 
<div ui-view="data"></div>
```

And in your app.config function

```
$stateProvider.state("home", {
    views: {
        "": {
            template: "<h1>Some HTML</h1>"
        },
        "chart": {
            templateUrl: "templates/chart.html"
        },
        "data": {
            template: "<data_thing/>"
        }
    }    
})
```